# how to use createEncodedImage method in jde 4.5

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

Can anyone know the way how to use createEncodedImage method of EncodedImage class in jde 4.5

Thanks and regards,
Vivek Birdi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you would do it if the Image was a resource file of the application:

```
byte[] imgData = null;
InputStream in = Application.getApplication().
        getClass().getResourceAsStream(imgName);
if(in == null) {
    // Handle appropriately
}

try {
    int length = in.available();
    imgData = new byte[length];
    in.read(bytes, 0, length);
} finally {
    in.close();
}

if(imgData == null) {
    // Handle appropriately
}

EncodedImage encodedImage = 
        EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(imgData, 0, imgData.length);
```

You could also pass a String as a parameter to define the MIME type.  These are the supported MIME types:

- "image/gif"
- "image/png"
- "image/vnd.wap.wbmp"
- "image/jpeg" (supported only on Colour devices)
- "image/jpg" (supported only on Colour devices)
- "image/pjpeg" (supported only on Colour devices)
- "image/bmp"
- "image/tiff"

Finally, here's the documentation for 4.5: [EncodedImage Javadocs 4.5][1]

[1]: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EncodedImage.html#createEncodedImage(byte[], int, int)

Comment: hi fostah, 

Thanks for your quick reply. But I am getting problem at line below:

byte[] imageData = Resource.getResourceClass().getResource("res_img.gif");

compiler giving error that getResourceClass() is undefined for Resource. And I could not find documentation for Resource class in blackberry jde 4.5 API.

Thanks and regards,
Vivek Birdi.

Comment: You're correct.  I'llupdate how to accomplish what Resource.getResourceClass().getResource() does.  Sorry about that.

Comment: ok,

But thanks a lot. I got the solution.

InputStream input = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("image.png");
EncodedImage encoded =null;
try{
     byte []b = new byte[input.available()];
     input.read(b);
     encoded = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(b, 0, b.length);
    }catch(Exception e){
 System.out.println("Exceptin "+ e);
     }

And image should be present in same package where we are writing the class or need some path to specify where we have located the image.